# Youtube API v3 Duration PlaylistItem

Tags: youtube-api, playlist, duration

If I get all Playlist Items with the Youtube Data API v3, I am getting this format for all videos:

```
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "KUL_AHeC4zw",
    "startAt": "PT0S",
    "endAt": "PT21M12.667S"
   }
```

Whats that thingie next to endAt? Why is there a point in the middle? I expect some kind of PT21M54S. I just want the duration as I would get it when I am fetching a single video. Is that a bug or am I just not able to understand that ISO Date Format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This field "`endAt`" is not the same as the "duration" of the video, but where the playlist owner wants it to stop playing. The video duration is located in the **video** resource ([`contentDetails.duration`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration)) and not in the **playlistItem**. And it requieres another lookup request.

You can find the definitions of the fields in the YouTube documentation. See for those resource definitions:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource
and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

Comment: Okay, Well the end is set to the real end of the video, which should be equal to the length? If the video is 3:10m long the end is most of the times 3:10m which is in fact the length of the video. I am confused about the format. How is 21M12.667S the end of a 21M53S video? Maybe I could get the difference of startAt and endAt to get the duration, but how could I achieve that if endAt is no valid point in time?

Comment: You're wrong: the value of this endAt, being "PT21M12.667S", is a valid point in time ! Here it is just NOT the end of the video; that's up to the playlist owner. And no you can't compute the duration. If it would please the owner, then he/she could change every endAt value, in which case all will be different from the duration.

Comment: I just want to see, how long a video is? That is all. What the playlist owner wants is a different topic

Comment: Then you need to make another request: get the video resource. BTW it's not determined by the playlist owner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"startAt": "PT0S",
"endAt": "PT21M12.667S"

This property has been deprecated and, if set, its value is ignored.

For More Info Check at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource